# model from ActiveRecord query has no attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, multiple-inheritance

I've been having some real problems getting my head around ActiveRecord and creating associations so I am sure my mistake is simple.

I have an `@user` object that I call the line:

```
@user = User.joins(researchers: :students).select(user_attributes).find(current_user.id)
```

where `user_attributes = 'researchers.year, users.givenname,`... ect.

This works fine. When I try to run a very similar line:

```
@supervisor = User.joins(researchers: :supervisors).select(supervisor_attributes).where('supervisor.student_id = ?', 1)
```

where the `supervisor_attributes = 'user.surname'`

I get a no method error when I try calling `@supervisor.surname` and I have absolutely no idea why.

I have tried a number or workarounds but I think there is a more fundamental error with my code and associations as below:

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  #Must have the following
  validates :name, :email, :surname, :email, :supervisor, :registration_number, presence: true
  #ensures unique email addresses
  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  #assosiations
  belongs_to :researcher
end
```

**supervisor.rb**

```
class Supervisor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :researcher
end
```

**researcher.rb**

```
class Researcher < ApplicationRecord
  #belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :supervisors
  has_many :students
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include EpiCas::DeviseHelper

  has_many :event_registrations
  has_many :events, through: :event_registrations
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :researchers
  has_many :students, :through => :researchers
  has_many :supervisors, :through => :researchers

  # def self.authenticate(username)
  #   where(username: username).first
  # end

  end
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Many Thanks,
James

Comment: May you post the error message

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be plural?

```
supervisor_attributes = 'users.surname'
```

Comment: You are right, it should be, but the same error occurs unfortunately, thanks though!

Comment: In the where to, `supervisors`

Comment: And you can rewrite that like `@supervisor = User.joins(researchers: :supervisors).select(supervisor_attributes).where(supervisors: { student_id: 1 })`

Comment: Again yes you are right again, when things go wrong for me I just try making different things plural and not plural in frustration (not helpful I know!) Unfortunately it is the same error still regardless of those two errors. Thank you though!

Comment: Wait, I got it. You have a ActiveRecord::Relation, not a single supervisor, this is the problem. Because the where. It is always a resultset, even with one element.

Comment: While in the first example you used `find`, not `where`.

Comment: Another good spot but not the issue! I finally found what was causing the problem, my supervisor record had nil for the researcher foreign key. I can't believe how many hours I have just wasted over this. Many thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following query

```
supervisor_attributes = 'users.surname'

@supervisor = User.joins(researchers: :supervisors).select(supervisor_attributes).where('supervisors.student_id = ?', 1)
```

In `where clause` you should use the `database` `table name`, as convention it should be plural `supervisors`.

Comment: Hi Rokibul, I just tried that and it is the same error as I got. Thanks though!